# Using swig Python wrapper: argument 2 of type 'std::unordered_set< std::string > const &'

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am updating an old project using (parent project of) the Python package [coqui_stt_ctcdecoder](https://pypi.org/project/coqui-stt-ctcdecoder/) generated from C++ using SWIG. Some parameter types in some methods have changed. I am stuck with the method [`Scorer::fill_dictionary`](https://github.com/coqui-ai/STT/blob/bb75afb8556595cf152a27bd4382b649e59b8e83/native_client/ctcdecode/scorer.h#L93) that takes `const std::unordered_set<std::string>&`  as an argument in C++. In [the old Python code](https://github.com/mozilla/DSAlign/blob/master/align/generate_package.py#L74) a list of `bytes` is passed, but that no longer works, as well as a set. I have no idea what type to put there. The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/d/shared/speech/dsalign/STT-align/align/align.py", line 693, in <module>
    main()
  File "/mnt/d/shared/speech/dsalign/STT-align/align/align.py", line 451, in main
    create_bundle(alphabet_path, scorer_path + '.' + 'lm.binary', scorer_path + '.' + 'vocab-500000.txt', scorer_path, False, 0.931289039105002, 1.1834137581510284)
  File "/mnt/d/shared/speech/dsalign/STT-align/align/generate_package.py", line 75, in create_bundle
    scorer.fill_dictionary(words)
  File "/mnt/d/shared/speech/dsalign/STT-align/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/coqui_stt_ctcdecoder/swigwrapper.py", line 1269, in fill_dictionary
    return _swigwrapper.Scorer_fill_dictionary(self, vocabulary)
TypeError: in method 'Scorer_fill_dictionary', argument 2 of type 'std::unordered_set< std::string > const &'
```

EDIT: I have tried a list and a set of `str` and `bytes`, all with the above exception. I have used Python 3.8 on Windows and WSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWIG includes support for `std::unordered_set`, but note that the interface oddly doesn't accept Python `set` objects.  `tuple` and `list` work, however.

Tested example:

**test.i**

```cpp
%module test

// Code injected into wrapper
%{
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

// Function using the parameter type from OP error message
void func(std::unordered_set<std::string> const &string_set) {
    for(auto& s : string_set)
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
%}

// SWIG support for templates
%include <std_unordered_set.i>
%include <std_string.i>
// Must instantiate the specific template used
%template(string_set) std::unordered_set<std::string>;

// Tell SWIG to wrap the function
void func(std::unordered_set<std::string> const &string_set);
```

Demo:

```py
>>> import test
>>> test.func(['abc','def','abc','ghi'])  # list works
abc
def
ghi
>>> s = test.string_set(['aaa','bbb','ccc','aaa','bbb'])
>>> test.func(s)
aaa
bbb
ccc
>>> s = test.string_set(('aaa','bbb','ccc','aaa','bbb')) # tuple works
>>> list(s)
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
>>> test.func({'abc','def'})  # set doesn't work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\test.py", line 194, in func
    return _test.func(string_set)
TypeError: in method 'func', argument 1 of type 'std::unordered_set< std::string,std::hash< std::string >,std::equal_to< std::string >,std::allocator< std::string > > const &'
```

Comment: So I guess the appropriate `%template` is missing in [the swig file](https://github.com/coqui-ai/STT/blob/main/native_client/ctcdecode/swigwrapper.i) and I need to resolve this with the maintainers, or is there a workaround?

Comment: @comodoro You could write your own `%typemap(in) std::unordered_set<std::string>` that supports `set` if you don't want to just convert the set to a list or tuple to call the function.

Comment: No, I mean I tried a list as well as a set to no avail, accidently deleted that from the question, sorry. I would have to recompile (which is tricky here), right?

Comment: @comodoro Yes you have to edit the SWIG .i file with %include and %template lines, run SWIG to generate the wrapper source and recompile

Answer (score 0):

A fix has been put in to work out the box for the swig-4.2.0 release.

The previous implementation used the Python Sequence Protocol to convert from Python types to STL containers. The new implementation uses the Python Iterator Protocol instead and thereby can convert from a Python set too.